# Problem Faced while searching Duplicate rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have been trying to find duplicate and got confused by 3 lines of codes. Can you please help me understand it?
Please find DESC of my table :

```
| Field      | Type                            | NULL | Key | Extra          |
| id         | int(11)                         | NO   | PRI | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(50)                     | YES  |     |                |
| membership | enum('Silver','Gold','Diamond') | YES  |     |                |
| interest   |set('Movie','Music','Concert')   | YES  |     |                |
```

This is the output for all the present data in table.
[Select * from clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu9PW.png)

```
+----+--------+------------+---------------+
| id | name   | membership | interest      |
+----+--------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | Sourav | Silver     | Movie,Concert |
|  2 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  3 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  4 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  5 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  6 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  7 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  8 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
|  9 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 10 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 11 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 12 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 13 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 14 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |
| 15 | Sneha  | Silver     | Concert       |
+----+--------+------------+---------------+
15 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Confusion arose in below three queries for why do they return 3 completely different outputs?

1.

```
SELECT id, name, membership, interest, count(*)
FROM clients
GROUP BY name, membership, interest
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

//This one being the correct line of code

```
+----+------+------------+----------+----------+
| id | name | membership | interest | count(*) |
+----+------+------------+----------+----------+
|  2 | Yash | Diamond    | Music    |       13 |
+----+------+------------+----------+----------+
```

2. SELECT name, membership, interest, count(*)
   FROM clients
   HAVING count(*) > 1;

   //Returns first entry with count as 15

   ```
     +--------+------------+---------------+----------+
     | name   | membership | interest      | count(*) |
     +--------+------------+---------------+----------+
     | Sourav | Silver     | Movie,Concert |       15 |
     +--------+------------+---------------+----------+
   ```
3. 

```
SELECT id, name, membership, interest, count(*)
FROM clients
GROUP BY name, membership, interest;
```

//Returns Unique Entries only while eliminating the duplicate entries. However, Sneha (last entry) was on top for some reason

```
+----+--------+------------+---------------+----------+
| id | name   | membership | interest      | count(*) |
+----+--------+------------+---------------+----------+
| 15 | Sneha  | Silver     | Concert       |        1 |
|  1 | Sourav | Silver     | Movie,Concert |        1 |
|  2 | Yash   | Diamond    | Music         |       13 |
+----+--------+------------+---------------+----------+
```

What necessary changes happened when I used  statement because given same syntax without  statement clause, it was working completely different.

In addition to that the last statement query was intriguing me as even though I did not apply any clause for Unique data, it delivered the same to me.

Finally, why did the last entry appeared at top in the 3. query?

Answer (score 0):

Correct query finding dupes in your case should be (one possibility as might be other solution as well),

```
select min(id) as id,
       name,
       membership,
       interest,
       count(*) as cnt
from clients
group by name,membership,interest
having count(*) > 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/HsV-S897

As per your tries.

The first query should fail with sql_mode only_full_group_by enabled which should be enabled .

In the second query HAVING without GROUP BY acts like WHERE, still the second query will fail with sql_mode only_full_group_by enabled.

The third query is correctly formed but you need `order by count(*) desc`  to get Yash   first.